# Error in Flutter while using Provider tool

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax, provider, pubspec

I am building a basic app using flutter, in which I had to use provider, I added Provider dependencies in pubspec.yaml file but getting this error please help, I added the error below not able to fix this problem I have the latest flutter SDK

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To solve this use `lower version` of **Provider** dependency as newer version of provider depends on newer version of **Flutter SDK** and your application's **Flutter SDK** is old one so it will have `compatibility issues,` So just `degrade` the version of `dependency` or you can also run **pub outdated** command and it will suggest you `compatible version` as per your SDK.